# Convert code to C#?

Tags: c#, php, hash, utf, sha512

I convert this code:

```
strtoupper(bin2hex(mhash(mhash_sha512, "$ico{$product[0]}{$user[1]}")));
```

into C#:

```
byte[] data = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(args[0]));
string result = "";
for(int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++)
    result += data[index].ToString("X2");
```

and it works very good. But if I try convert input into UTF16:

```
strtoupper(bin2hex(mhash(mhash_sha512, iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', "$ico{$product[0]}{$user[1]}"))));
```

and in C# convert using Encoding class:

```
SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII/UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16"), Encoding.ASCII/UTF8.GetBytes(args[0])));
```

it not working. I need to get the same output from both languages. How can I correctly convert string ("bbb") into UTF16 in C# language? Thank you...

Comment: iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', DATA) versus Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16"), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(args[0])) -- where's your reference to UTF-8 in the csharp code?  You're using ASCII not UTF-8 in the cs code.

Comment: I have ASCII in C# - not UTF8... Therefore I convert from ASCII into UTF16 in C# code. But PHP is in UTF8... But CodePage is small problem of this conversion. For examle - What is equivalent for mhash in C#? I'm not sure anything - that's why I'm asking here...

Comment: Why do you need it in UTF16? Why not just use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args[0])`?

Comment: Security? :) (I want hard algorithm...)

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question so that the problem you are having becomes clearer. Add some code that shows what you have tried, what the expected outcome is and what has failed / is wrong.

Comment: What are the hash codes actually produced by the examples you have included? See my updated answer below, you may want to experiment a little bit with the same literal string as input and different encodings.

Comment: Due to the fact that ASCII/UTF8 doesn't affect on anything in the C# code, I don't understand why UTF16 yes. Why and where is the difference in conversion into UTF16 between those languages​​?

Answer (score 4):

In case of little endian UTF-16 encoding, change `Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16")` to `Encoding.Unicode` in case of big endian UTF-16, change it to 'Encoding.BigEndianUnicode`.

Upon further inspection (e.g. UTF-8 is not the same as Encoding.ASCII), would this be a good translation of your PHP code?

```
var bytesToHash = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args[0]));
var result = string.Concat(SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(bytesToHash).Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
```

I am not familiar with the expected output of this php mhash function, but perhaps you could try this:

```
var hash = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data));
var hashString = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
var phpLikeHash = hashString.Replace("-", String.Empty).ToUpper();
```

**UPDATE**
Ok, so based upon your new information the first example I included would work if no encoding conversion of the input is required. So this at least confirms that we can rely on the SHA512 producing the same output as PHP's mhash in the way you use it, and that any differences are related to the bytes provided as input.

I would suggest you experiment a bit with different encodings using the same literal string as input in both PHP code and c#. Like e.g. below:

```
    static bool HashIt(Encoding source, Encoding dest, string input, string expectedOutput)
    {
        byte[] bytes = source.GetBytes(input);
        if (source != dest && dest != null)
            bytes =  Encoding.Convert(source, dest, bytes);
        var hash = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(bytes);
        var hashString = string.Concat(hash.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
        if (hashString.Equals(expectedOutput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match found");
            Console.WriteLine("Source encoding: {0}", source.WebName);
            if (source != dest && dest != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Converted to: {0}", dest.WebName);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inputs = new [] { "13338170AS875HEO49F8Sam-PC", @"13338170AS875HEO49F8Sam-PC" };
        var expectedOutput = "A91A64DD4DF1880651CB6B919BE02C4363ED6D4B07EA246CF47FFB509918E4AA4C294FF8BA9F73E5‌​CD1CE463BB3E66F84A6C294D70C781CD0610345BCADEEDA7";
        var encodings = Encoding.GetEncodings().Select(e => e.GetEncoding());
        var matchFound = false;
        foreach (var srcEncoding in encodings)
        {
            foreach (var input in inputs)
            {
                if (HashIt(srcEncoding, null, input, expectedOutput))
                    matchFound = true;
                foreach (var destEncoding in encodings)
                {
                    if (HashIt(srcEncoding, destEncoding, input, expectedOutput))
                        matchFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!matchFound)
            Console.WriteLine("No matches found");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Which produces the following output on my system:

```
No matches found
```

So you may be out of luck. I don't see at this time what else to try.

Comment: I tried your code with correct input (13338170AS875HEO49F8Sam-PC) and I'm not find compliance... Correct output:

A91A64DD4DF1880651CB6B919BE02C4363ED6D4B07EA246CF47FFB509918E4AA4C294FF8BA9F73E5‌​CD1CE463BB3E66F84A6C294D70C781CD0610345BCADEEDA7 (PHP)

Comment: Oops sorry, it is SHA512, not 256. I will update my answer :D

Comment: No matches found... :) And what Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16")?

Comment: The code above in my updated answer checks all combinations of encodings available on my system. None of them match.

Comment: What does doing PHP differently? :)

(iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', "$ico{$product[0]}{$user[1]}"))

Comment: Did you try changing your PHP code so it uses the same literal string as input, i.e. iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', utf8_encode('13338170AS875HEO49F8Sam-PC'))

Comment: No no - read the question please. I have result in UTF8 encoding. But now I'm asking for result for UTF16 encoding...

Comment: As a way to troubleshoot the problem, I suggest that you change your PHP code to use the exact same inputs, to exclude the possibility that what is retrieved though "$ico{$product[0]}{$user[1]}" is not identical to a UTF-8 encoded "13338170AS875HEO49F8Sam-PC".

Comment: Why UTF8 working? (And in C# UTF8/ASCII.) If I use UTF8 result, I can use UTF8/ASCII in C#... Why is problem in UTF16?

Comment: @Alex +1 for the time and hard work this seems one of those hard clients.